# Error: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient

Tags: .net

An error occurs in .net application when attempting to connect to an OLAP cube:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient, Version=XX.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft® SQL Server® ADOMD.NET is missing from the machine.

It can be downloaded from the "Microsoft® SQL Server® Feature Pack" ([SQL 2012 version here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35580)) - choose the ADOMD.NET component e.g. SQL_AS_ADOMD.msi for your processor architecture.